# How to get correct timestamp from UTC datetime

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

In my program, I need to use a datetime object that is in utc time not my local time, and I also need the timestamp (seconds since epoch) of that datetime object.

```
import datetime

my_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
timestamp = my_time.timestamp()
```

However, the timestamp was wrong. It was the timestamp when my local time is `my_time`, not the correct timestamp when the utc time is `my_time`. How can I get the correct timestamp? I don't want to create another datetime object because there might be microseconds of difference.

**Edit**

Example:

```
import datetime

utc_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
local_time = datetime.datetime.now()

utc_timestamp = utc_time.timestamp()
local_timestamp = local_time.timestamp()

print(utc_timestamp)
print(local_timestamp)
```

My result:

```
1633133103.945903
1633161903.945903
```

The two are different by 8 hours, because I live in UTC+08:00 time zone, and the first one is not "seconds since epoch". I want to get the correct timestamp from `utc_time` because technically those two object were not created at the same time.

Comment: please add your expected output

Comment: What is your time zone, and the discrepancy from UTC? Do other time-related utilities on your system report UTC time correctly?

Comment: the problem here is that `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` gives a naive datetime object, that has attributes set to current UTC time - however, since the ***object is naive***, Python will treat it like ***local time*** - which is why `.timestamp()` returns an unexpected result. I therefore suggest to avoid `utcnow()` altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [aware datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects),

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

t_loc = datetime.now().astimezone() # local time, as set in my OS (tz Europe/Berlin)
t_utc = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

print(repr(t_loc))
print(repr(t_utc))
# e.g.
# datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 2, 11, 10, 26, 920792, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200), 'CEST'))
# datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 2, 9, 10, 26, 920809, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

This will give you correct Unix time as well:

```
t_loc_unix = t_loc.timestamp()
t_utc_unix = t_utc.timestamp()

print(t_loc_unix, t_utc_unix)
# 1633165826.920792 1633165826.920809
```

Unix timestamps are now equal as it should be since Unix time always (should) refers to UTC.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64097432/10197418