# How to format this datetime

Tags: python

A library is returning this timestamp:

```
2022-01-11T11:23:50.457-0500
```

i'd like to format it to UTC like this:

```
2022-01-11 16:23:50.457
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert local time string to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-to-convert-local-time-string-to-utc)

Comment: You should tell us of what type the returned timestamp is. Is it a _str_, a _datetime.datetime_ or something else?

Comment: @WolfgangKuehn Sorry, it is a str

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a `datetime.datetime` object you could do

```py
datetime_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

If all you have is a string you can do

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(
    '2022-01-11T11:23:50.457-0500',
    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z',
)
datetime_obj.astimezone(tz=timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

[Here's the doc for the parsing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

[Here's the doc for changing the timezone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone)