# Convert Date time to UTC Time in python

Tags: python, utc, pytz

I have datetime value in format of `2022-01-26T07:01:36-08:00` (based on which user fetches data, it will have local timezone, like `-08:00`, `+05:30`)

I want to convert this time into UTC Time.

I saw multiple example of pytz but couldn't figure out how to convert using pytz or datetime. datetime value will be based on machine timezone so I can't hard code timezone value also.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-to-convert-local-time-string-to-utc) if the solution doesn't work, please provide the code you tried

Comment: TL;DR: parse the string into a `datetime` object, then just do `.astimezone(timezone.utc)`.